# What did English people really say when knighting someone?

Tags: england, ceremony, chivalry

A while ago I curiously looked up this question and found out that people did not say "I dub thee..." or "Arise..." to him who was being made a knight, but instead used a Latin phrase which I forget. It translated to something like "knight advance in God's name" – something like that. I really want to remember now, but I cannot find any website anywhere that says anything like that again.

What was the phrase?

I've asked before at [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294028), but I was directed to ask it here, so I hope this works and I will very much appreciate an answer.

Comment: Arise, Sir Loin of Beef!

Comment: There are different orders of chivalry so there's no universal form of words.

Comment: What *did* English people say? Knighthoods are still conferred.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Which English? Saxons, Normans, Romans etc. If you realise the history of when these practices started to take place, it was never in English.

Comment: @JamesRyan The question says "What did English people really say when knighting somebody?" My point (which I agree I put far too obliquely)  is that writing the question in the past tense suggests that English (properly, British) knighthoods no longer exist. However, as I pointed out, they *do* still exist. It would be more appropriate to ask the question in the present tense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby they don't say the same thing now though!

Comment: @JamesRyan The question still implies that British knighthoods no longer exist.

Comment: @DavidRicherby well they kind of don't.  It is just an honourary title now, in the past it actually meant something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [the British Monarchy website](http://www.royal.gov.uk/MonarchUK/Honours/Knighthoods.aspx):

> The first and simplest method of knighting was that used on
>   battlefields, when the candidate knelt before the Royal commander of
>   the army and was 'stricken with the sword upon his back and shoulder'
>   with some words such as 'Advances Chevalier au nom de Dieu'. (The
>   action of touching the sword on the recipient's shoulder is known as
>   dubbing.)

So the reason you could not find the phrase in Latin is because it was in French.

**Edit**, [MerilP](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/15720/meril-p) notes that in French it should actually be 'Avancez Chevalier au nom de Dieu' and 'Soyez preux, hardi, et loyal'.

Comment: I haven't found any mention of the modern wording, they may have kept the French version as a nod to tradition or, since the ceremony is considerably shortened these days, it might have been skipped altogether.

Comment: The final three paragraphs of that page seem to suggest that the Queen does not say anything, and just lays a sword blade on the kneeling knight's right and then left shoulder.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it! I appreciate that very much. I thought I remembered  copying it and pasting it into Google Translate it detecting that the language was Latin. But I am a very forgetful person so it very well may have been French.

Comment: @Rathony the church was latin, the norman aristocracy spoke french

Comment: "Advances Chevalier" is not proper French as spoken in France; it English "Legal French".

Comment: @fdb languages change in spelling, usage and pronounciation over time. Quite possibly it was said differently then, and the dominant dialect would have been Norman French rather than the "pure" ile de france variant that dominates today

Comment: @bigbadmouse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_French

Comment: @fdb And of course that is the language an English (Norman) monarch would use post-Conquest.

Answer (score 18):

If it was really Latin that you saw, then it might have been:

> ***Surge aut sis eques in nomine Dei*** <sup>**1**</sup>
>   Stand up as a knight, in the name of God.

This is how [William Camden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Camden) described the ancient [ceremony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accolade) in his *Britannia*. There are variations, such as substituting `vel` for `aut`. I'd be a bit surprised if the site you originally found actually used Latin, though.

---

Since you expected to find the answer in English ("I dub thee"), I suppose the question is focused on England. In that case, as @SteveBird's rightly points out, the traditional words are in French, not Latin. Complementing his answer, the classical formula is for the sovereign to lay a naked blade on the candidate's left shoulder and pronounce:

> ***Sois chevalier, au nom de Dieu*** <sup>**2**</sup>
>   (Be thou a knight in the name of God)

Followed by the command to rise:

> ***Avancez chevalier*** <sup>**2**</sup>
>   (Arise, knight)

---

The use of French has long since died out in English governance. In later times, it appears the monarch simply pronounce:

> **Rise up, Sir (name)** <sup>**3**</sup>

---

This part is possibly slightly profane. Mouseover to show.

> Jake Cade: *Rise up, Sir Dick Butcher*
>
>
>   **<sub>- William Shakespeare, [*3 Henry VI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VI,_Part_3) (certain [versions](https://books.google.com/books?id=s8UkAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA72&ots=fF9-zh3p7L&dq="sir+dick+butcher"&pg=PA72&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)).</sub>**

---

**Sources:**

<sub>**[1]** Jacob, Giles, and Thomas Edlyne Tomlins. *The Law-Dictionary: Explaining the Rise, Progress, and Present State, of the English Law*. A. Strahan, Law Printer to the King's Most Excellent Majesty, 1809.</sub>
<sub>**[2]** Burke, John Bernard. *The Knightage of Great Britain and Ireland*. London: Edward Churton, 1841.</sub>
<sub>**[3]** Cox, Thomas, and William Camden. *Magna Britannia et Hibernia, Antiqua & Nova Or, A New Survey of Great Britain*. Savoy: Nutt and Morphew, 1720.</sub>

Comment: How is a common first name "profane" sigh. Clbuttic mistake!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humour

Comment: That's hilariarse!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Richard Burton (of *Liz and Dick* fame, not the other one) was known to despise the nickname *Dick*, often remarking with words to the effect "Dick's not a name; it's a body part."

Answer (score 7):

The famous English antiquary, Elias Ashmole, wrote:

> The first Christian Kings and Princes (saith in Favin) at the giving
>   of the *Cingulum militare*, kissed the new Knight on the left cheek,
>   and used these words, *In the honor of the Father, of the Son; and of
>   the Holy Ghost, I make you a Knight*. And this was called *Osculum
>   pacis*, the kiss of Favour or Brotherhood.

He is citing Andre Favin who wrote the book Theatre d'Honneur et de Chevalerie, an early and well-known tome on chivalry in the 16th century.

Of course, what might be said at various times and places would be completely different and the ceremony could range from being perfunctory or elaborate. As a general rule, a knighting pronouncement had three parts, the admonition (warnings and advice), the blessing and the bestowal (the actual title(s) and rank conferred announced).

Comment: there is a mention of dubbing knights in the play Henry V